# selecting not None value from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use the `fillna` function to fill None value of a column with its own first most frequent value that is not None or nan.

Input DF:

```
Col_A
a
None
None
c
c
d
d
```

The output Dataframe could be either:

```
Col_A
a
c
c
c
c
d
d
```

Any suggestion would be very appreciated. 
Many Thanks, Best Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prelude: If your `None` is actually a *string*, you can simplify any headaches by getting rid of them first-up. Use `replace`:

```
df = df.replace('None', np.nan)
```

---

I believe you could use `fillna` + `value_counts`:

```
df

  Col_A
0     a
1   NaN
2   NaN
3     c
4     c
5     d
6     d

df.fillna(df.Col_A.value_counts(sort=False).index[0])

  Col_A
0     a
1     c
2     c
3     c
4     c
5     d
6     d
```

Or, with Vaishali's suggestion, use `idxmax` to pick `c`:

```
df.fillna(df.Col_A.value_counts(sort=False).idxmax())

  Col_A
0     a
1     c
2     c
3     c
4     c
5     d
6     d
```

The fill-values could either be `c` or `d`, depending on whether you include `sort=False` or not.

**Details**

```
df.Col_A.value_counts(sort=False)

c    2
a    1
d    2
Name: Col_A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: or value_counts().idxmax() though that would give 'd' again.

Comment: @Vaishali No, you are correct. As long as `sort=False`, anything will work.

Comment: Never paid attention to sort parameter in value_counts(), good one:)

Comment: Hi Vaishali, Thanks. When applying to my date I am getting the error: ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

Comment: Interesting df.Col_A.value_counts(sort=False) for me returns A 1, C 2, D 2 in that order.

Comment: @CarloAllocca We would need you to produce an example that reproduces your problem. If sort_values returns nothing, your dataframe only has NaNs.

Comment: @ScottBoston Wow, really? I'm running `'0.20.2'`, wbu?

Comment: Nope.  lastest version 0.21.0

Comment: Sorry, I have in my case that Col_A is float64 and when I am applying your suggested solution I am getting "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"   OR "ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence"

Comment: Please, can I use df.fillna(df["Col_A"].value_counts(sort=False).idxmax())? as in my case I have got Col_A is in reality Col.A

Comment: @CarloAllocca I thought you accepted Wen’s answer because that’s what you’re using?

Comment: No, I am not. I am trying to use yours, which works when exist at least a value which is not nan

Comment: @CarloAllocca you have many questions. Can you write a new post? Detail your specific problem and I’ll try to help. Comments aren’t the best place to start solving new problems.

Comment: Um, not sure how I helped, but np.

Answer (score 2):

`fillna` + `mode`

```
df.Col_A.fillna(df.Col_A.mode()[0])
Out[963]: 
0    a
1    c
2    c
3    c
4    c
5    d
6    d
Name: Col_A, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Wen, Thanks. What about if mode is None?

Comment: @CarloAllocca you can first replace None to np.nan

Comment: @CarloAllocca The assumption here is that None = np.nan. If not (if it's a string), call `df = df.replace('None', np.nan)`  and then both our answers work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To address 'None', you need to use `replace` then `fillna` much like @COLDSPEED suggests:

```
dr = df.Col_A.replace('None',np.nan)
dr.fillna(dr.dropna().value_counts().index[0])
```

Output:

```
0    a
1    d
2    d
3    c
4    c
5    d
6    d
Name: Col_A, dtype: object
```